# How do assemblers handle a value that is separated on 2 registers (e.g EDX:EAX)?

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, integer-division

I'm trying to understand how do assemblers handle these.

Currently I'm trying to learn to code assembly by writing an assembly code manually. But I'm wondering how to handle a product that is separated by EDX:EAX after the operand "MUL".

What if I want to integer divide that value now by a another value, how do you do that in assembly?

Comment: the assembler just converts human-reading instructions into machine code, it doesn't "handle" anything. That's the CPU that process the instructions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MUL and DIV are designed both to use EDX:EAX register pair -- implicitly.

Where MUL uses those as output registers, DIV uses those as input registers. Depending on your problem, you don't necessarily have to do anything -- just ignore the other register, since DIV actually calculates also the remainder of the division, placing it to edx.

```
 12313133*81231313 / 4342434 -->
  
 mov eax, 12313133
 mov ebx, 81231313
 imul ebx               ;; edx:eax = 38DAF:FE9E9FBD
 mov ebx, 4342434
 idiv ebx

 mov [my_result], eax   ;; = 230334407
 mov [remainder], edx
```

Beware that DIV and IDIV will *fault* (`#DE` exception) if the quotient doesn't fit in EAX.  Using a dividend that isn't sign- or zero- extended from one register makes it possible for this to happen for cases other than `INT_MIN / -1` or `anything / 0`.

For unsigned 32-bit `div r32`, it will fault if `EDX >= r32`, otherwise not.

If you're using `x * a / b` with just one mul and div, make sure `|a| < |b|` or that your input `x` is always small enough.

Comment: I didn't realize that DIV uses EDX:EAX as input. That is where I got confused when trying to trace the assembly code in gdb, I thought that DIV will just use EAX divided by the input divisor. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure to store the product.  Here I use 32 bit code, and multiply 1073741824 by 25, which the result will be more than a 32 bit register can hold, so it will go into edx:eax.

This is MASM code for the example.

```
include masm32rt.inc

sProduct struct 
    LoDWord  DD ?
    HiDWord  DD ?
sProduct ends

.data
fmtint      db  "%lld", 13, 10,  0

.data?
Product     sProduct <?>

.code
start:

    mov     eax, 1073741824
    mov     ecx, 25
    mul     ecx

    mov     Product.HiDWord, edx
    mov     Product.LoDWord, eax

    invoke  crt_printf, offset fmtint,  Product
    inkey
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

And testing with calc to make sure the result is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally that means there's a doubleword multiply--with the 8 byte result being stored in EDX:EAX--with the high-order 32-bits of the result stored in EDX.